# All comment forms submit the same docId

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react app (a sort of twitter clone) that uses firestore for storing posts and comments on posts.  Each post is rendered as an element from an array using array.map().  Each post has a comment button that opens a form to take in a comment and add it to the post.  When I enter a comment and submit it, the topmost post is always the one commented on no matter which post contained the comment button that was clicked(docId for the most recently saved firestore document is always submitted by the comment button instead of the docId corresponding to that instance of the component).

The map of the posts (called "howls"):

```
<div className="timeline">
  {sortedHowls &&
    sortedHowls.map((howl) => (
      <Howl
        key={howl.id}
        image={howl.image}
        text={howl.text}
        time={howl.time}
        userId={howl.userId}
        docId={howl.id}
        comments={howl.comments}
        likes={howl.likes}
      />
    ))}
</div>
```

The Howl Component looks like this:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useFirestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { firestore } from "../../../firebase-store";
// styles
import "./Howl.scss";
// components
import Avatar from "../Avatar/Avatar";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
// functions
import timeCalc from "./timeCalc";
// icons
import { faStar, faComment } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Howl = ({ docId, userId, text, image, time, comments, likes }) => {
  useFirestoreConnect([{ collection: "users" }]);

  const [commenting, toggleCommenting] = useState(false);
  const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const getUsers = useSelector((state) => state.firestore.ordered.users);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!users) {
      setUsers(getUsers);
    } else {
      setUser(users.find((doc) => doc.uid === userId));
    }
  }, [users, user, userId, getUsers]);

  const handleLike = () => {
    const newLikesTotal = likes + 1;
    firestore.collection("howls").doc(docId).update({ likes: newLikesTotal });
  };

  const handleComment = () => {
    toggleCommenting(!commenting);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNewComment(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const submitComment = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { id } = event.currentTarget;
    console.log(event.currentTarget);

    const resetComment = () => {
      toggleCommenting(!commenting);
      setNewComment("");
    };

    if (comments) {
      firestore
        .collection("howls")
        .doc(id)
        .update({
          comments: [...comments, newComment],
        })
        .then(() => resetComment());
    } else {
      firestore
        .collection("howls")
        .doc(id)
        .update({ comments: [newComment] })
        .then(() => resetComment());
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="howl">
      <div className="avatar-container">
        <Avatar
          photoURL={user ? user.photoURL : ""}
          displayName={user ? user.displayName : ""}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="name-text-img-container">
        <p className="userName">
          {user && user.displayName} - {timeCalc(Date.now(), time)}
        </p>
        <p className="howl-text">{text}</p>
        <div className="img-container">
          {image ? (
            <img src={image} alt="user uploaded" className="img" />
          ) : null}
        </div>
        <div className="buttons-container">
          <form action="" className="buttons">
            <label htmlFor="comment-button">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} className="image-icon" />
            </label>
            <input
              id="comment-button"
              type="checkbox"
              onClick={handleComment}
              style={{ display: "none" }}
            />
            <label htmlFor="like-button">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} className="image-icon" />
            </label>
            <input
              id="like-button"
              type="checkbox"
              onClick={handleLike}
              style={{ display: "none" }}
            />
            <label htmlFor="like-button">{likes > 0 && likes}</label>
          </form>
        </div>
        {commenting && (
          <div className="comment-form">
            <form action="submit" onSubmit={submitComment} id={docId}>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="comment-input"
                className="comment-input"
                maxLength={128}
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={newComment}
                placeholder="Enter comment"
              />
              <div className="buttons">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                <button onClick={() => toggleCommenting(!commenting)}>
                  Cancel
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className="comments">
          {comments
            ? comments.map((comment, index) => {
                return (
                  <p key={index} className="comment">
                    {comment}
                  </p>
                );
              })
            : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Howl;
```

How can I get the comment button to specify the correct document to update?

Link to my full [repo](https://github.com/JonathanDPotter/howler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is here:

```
     <form action="" className="buttons">
        <label htmlFor="comment-button">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} className="image-icon" />
        </label>
        <input
          id="comment-button"
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={handleComment}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
        <label htmlFor="like-button">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStar} className="image-icon" />
        </label>
        <input
          id="like-button"
          type="checkbox"
          onClick={handleLike}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
        <label htmlFor="like-button">{likes > 0 && likes}</label>
      </form>
```

By using a form and inputs as the buttons instead of using `<button />` elements it somehow confused react as to which instance of `<Howl />` was opening the comment form and therefore which docId was sent to submitComment.  Corrected `<Howl />` component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useFirestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { firestore } from "../../../firebase-store";
// components
import Avatar from "../Avatar/Avatar";
import CommentInput from "./CommentInput";
import Comment from "./Comment";
import ViewProfile from "../ViewProfile/ViewProfile";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
// functions
import timeCalc from "./timeCalc";
// styles
import "./Howl.scss";
// icons
import { faStar, faComment } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Howl = ({ howl }) => {
  useFirestoreConnect([{ collection: "users" }]);

  const [commenting, toggleCommenting] = useState(false);
  const [newComment, setNewComment] = useState("");
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
  const [op, setOp] = useState(null);
  const [showProfile, setShowProfile] = useState(false);

  const { docId, userId, text, likes, comments, time, image } = howl;

  const getUsers = useSelector((state) => state.firestore.ordered.users);

  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.firebase.auth);

  // establish user that posted this howl (op = original poster)
  useEffect(() => {
    users ? setOp(users.find((doc) => doc.uid === userId)) : setUsers(getUsers);
  }, [users, op, userId, getUsers]);

  const handleLike = () => {
    const index = likes.indexOf(currentUser.uid);
    let newLikes = [...likes];

    if (index > 0) {
      newLikes.splice(index, 1);
    } else if (index === 0) {
      if (likes.length > 1) {
        newLikes.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        newLikes = [];
      }
    } else {
      newLikes = [...newLikes, currentUser.uid];
    }

    firestore.collection("howls").doc(docId).update({ likes: newLikes });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNewComment(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const submitComment = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { id } = event.currentTarget;
    const { uid, photoURL } = currentUser;

    const resetComment = () => {
      toggleCommenting(!commenting);
      setNewComment("");
    };

    firestore
      .collection("howls")
      .doc(id)
      .update({
        comments: [
          ...comments,
          { uid: uid, photoURL: photoURL, text: newComment },
        ],
      })
      .then(() => resetComment());
  };

  return (
    <div className="howl">
      <div className="avatar-container">
        <button className="show-profile" onClick={() => setShowProfile(true)}>
          <Avatar
            photoURL={op ? op.photoURL : ""}
            displayName={op ? op.displayName : ""}
          />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="name-text-img-container">
        <p className="userName">
          {op && op.displayName} - {timeCalc(Date.now(), time)}
        </p>
        <p className="howl-text">{text}</p>
        <div className="img-container">
          {image && <img src={image} alt="user uploaded" className="img" />}
        </div>
        <div className="buttons-container">
          <div className="buttons">
            <button className="comment-button">
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faComment}
                className="image-icon"
                onClick={() => toggleCommenting(!commenting)}
              />
            </button>
            <button className="like-button" onClick={handleLike}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faStar}
                className={
                  currentUser && likes.includes(currentUser.uid)
                    ? "image-icon liked"
                    : "image-icon"
                }
              />
            </button>
            <p>{likes.length > 0 && likes.length}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {commenting && (
          <CommentInput
            submitComment={submitComment}
            docId={docId}
            toggleCommenting={toggleCommenting}
            commenting={commenting}
            handleChange={handleChange}
            newComment={newComment}
          />
        )}
        {showProfile && (
          <ViewProfile
            user={op}
            close={() => setShowProfile(false)}
            update={false}
          />
        )}
        <div className="comments">
          {comments &&
            comments.map((comment, index) => {
              return <Comment key={`comment${index}`} comment={comment} />;
            })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Howl;
```